# Убрать дубли из результата запроса двух таблиц

Tags: sql

У меня есть запрос:

```
select distinct(KEEP_ORGANIZATION) from GOV_ETALON where KEEP_ORGANIZATION is not null
union all
select distinct(STORED_ETALON) from REGISTER_ETALON where STORED_ETALON is not null,
```

но дело в том, что в первой и второй таблице, существуют одинаковые значения, например:
в табл. *GOV_ETALON* в поле *KEEP_ORGANIZATION* есть значение «Велком+», и в
в табл. *REGISTER_ETALON* в поле *STORED_ETALON* есть значение «Велком+»,

Как в результате запроса оставить только один «Велком+»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы к сожалению не указали, о диалекте какой именно СУБД идет речь. Но большинство современных СУБД (Oracle, MsSql, MySQL) поддерживают вложенные запросы select:

```
select distinct * from
 (
   select distinct(KEEP_ORGANIZATION) from GOV_ETALON where KEEP_ORGANIZATION is not null
    union all
   select distinct(STORED_ETALON) from REGISTER_ETALON where STORED_ETALON is not null
 ) T
```

Алиас для подзапроса (в примере `T`) необходим для части СУБД, некоторые могут обходится без него

Comment: FireBird (Dialect 3)

Comment: Да, это оно. Можно без алиаса "Т". 
Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: (может это надо создать новую тему...), но не подскажите ли, можно его объединить этот запрос с запросом "**select first 1 (select min(YEAR_ETALON) as MIN_YEAR from GOV_ETALON),
  (select max(YEAR_ETALON) as MAX_YEAR from GOV_ETALON) from GOV_ETALON**", таким образом, чтобы было 3 поля "*MIN_YEAR*", "*MAX_YEAR*" с этого запроса и "*KEEP_ORGANIZATION*" с запроса (см. выше)???

Comment: Я правда не понял сокровенного смысла этого select 1 first. Если строки из 1 запроса и в каждой строке еще 2 поля, с одинаковыми для всех строк значениями, то в моем общем запросе после алиаса T через запятую ваши два подселекта. но у меня ощущение что вы хотите чего то большего. типа min/mаx для конкретной категории

Comment: И кстати я даже не понял зачем 2 подхапроса для Min/max: вроде так проще select min(YEAR_ETALON) as MIN_YEAR,max(YEAR_ETALON) as MAX_YEAR from GOV_ETALON

Comment: да, спасибо - этот запрос **действительно проще**. А смысл мой, в том, что это два запроса, которые формируют список *DBComboBox*, при состояниях *DataSet* = ("Insert" or "Edit"). И чтобы не делать два раза запрос,  я хочу это сделать в одном.

Comment: Ну если данные независимы, то собственно select distinct * from (... union ...) T, (select min(YEAR_ETALON) as MIN_YEAR,max(YEAR_ETALON) as MAX_YEAR from GOV_ETALON) A  Ну или может вверху select distinct T.*,A.* или имена полей указывать, это в зависимости от требований языка

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!, как раз то, что нужно

Comment: Так конечно можно убрать дубли, но зачем возводить такой многоэтажный запрос, когда для этого есть естественный способ?

Comment: Логично :) Что то я забыл о свойствах union, вернее all никогда не юзал и подумал раз спрашивают, значит проблема :)

Answer (score 4):

Вот так дубли должны быть уничтожены

```
select distinct(KEEP_ORGANIZATION) from GOV_ETALON where KEEP_ORGANIZATION is not null
union
select distinct(STORED_ETALON) from REGISTER_ETALON where STORED_ETALON is not null
```

`UNION` - Убирает дубли из результат
`UNION ALL` - Сохраняет дубли в результате. Собственно для этого ALL и был добавлен.